# Are we allowed to cancel the units of a derivative?

Tags: differentiation, dimensional-analysis, units, calculus

Since the volume of a sphere $v(r)=\frac{4}{3} \pi r^{3} \left[m^{3}\right]$, its derivative relative to the radius is:
$$
\frac{dv}{dr} =4\pi r^{2} \left[\frac{m^{3}}{m}\right]
$$
Which is also a formula for the area of the sphere surface. While mathematically the expressions are identical, can we actually simplify the units to $\left[m^{2}\right]$? This feels a little wrong because the phenomena that we describe is the rate of change, not the area.

So does such simplification make sense from the physics perspective? And if not, how do we denote this in our expressions?

**CLARIFICATION** to some commenters: I don't mean to say that you can't cancel out units at all. I'm saying that it may depend on the quantity that you want to report. If you're reporting an area, then sure - cancel it all out to $m^2$, but if you report the rate of change, then it $m^2$ doesn't look right to me.

Comment: This is **clearly** a conceptual question. It is obviously *not* a "check-my-work" question! Voting to reopen.

Comment: Agree with @PM2Ring

Comment: If we take something like distance $S=1/2\  a \ t^2 =1/2\  dv/dt \ t^2= [m][s^2][s^{-2}]= [m]$ the result is physically a distance and no longer a rate of change.

Answer (score 5):

The unit cancellation does work.  Sometimes units work out in interesting ways.  My favorite is [specific impulse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specific_impulse), a ratio of thrust produced per unit weight.  The units work out to simply be seconds!

> This feels a little wrong because the phenomena that we describe is the rate of change, not the area.

Perhaps your intuition might be getting confused by the fact that we have a rate of change per unit length, when the more typical things that we think of as a "rate of change" are a rate of change per unit time, which would lead us to having a unit of time (like seconds) in the denominator.

In the end, the units work out.  If we go all the way back to the definition of a derivative:

$$\frac{dv}{dr}=\lim_{h\to 0}{\frac{v(r+h)-v(r)}{h}}$$

we can see that that derivative really becomes a division operation.  Dividing a volume by a length yields area.  The fact that we then take a limit of that division doesn't change the nature of the division itself.

An informal way to think about this particular derivative is that if you add an infinitesimally small shell's worth of volume, that volume is the area of the sphere times that infinitesimal thickness.  In that view, the nature of the derivative as an area may be more apparent.

For more on the concept, its worth reading about [physical quantities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_quantity).  That is the metrology concept which captures ideas such as "a scalar with units."  A lot of effort has gone into coming up with an accepted approach to units.

Comment: I draw extra attention to the fact that this is a division because the OP raises a good concern: units are not well defined for some operations in math.  Logarithms, I'm looking at you!  But in the case of differentiation, we can go to the definition of differentiation to prove that they are indeed well defined here.

Comment: Interestingly, all your points make me feel even more that the units can't be cancelled :) I think what physicists do is they _replace_ one notion (rate of change) with another (area in this case). It all works out in the end because the calculations are identical. And when used in more complicated calculations the units still cancel out at another step. But it still feels like the "rate of change" and "area" are two distinct notions. And the rate of change is always a quotient (it's a rate!). It may be unimportant for the end goal (predictions), but it obfuscates the actual physical process.

Comment: Perhaps a better example of a similar process is taking a 1D vector and replacing it with a scalar. The amount of information is the same. You can change your operations from doing dot product to using scalar operations. And end up with the same value. But while in the case of $\frac{m^3}{m}$ vs $m^2$ you don't have to change the algorithm, in the case of 1D vectors vs scalars you do need to change the steps to accommodate different math procedures. But it's basically the same process: you change the _presentation_, the _structure_ of the information.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev I agree there's something not fully captured in the units.  If you try to compare the vacuum ISP of the Falcon 9 rocket (311s) against the time it takes to cook a baked potato in a microwave (about 5 minutes), you have not found a meaningful comparison, even if the units line up. That being said, there is an accepted axiomatic theory of simple units, such that $5[m^3]/1[m]$ does indeed equal $5[m^2]$, with no concern as to whether it is a rate or an area.  The units simply work that way.  And by an accepted theory, I mean there's an ISO document codifying it (ISO 80000-1)

Comment: I added a link to the wikipedia page on physical quantities.  That's probably the best place to go to start answering questions about units.

Comment: My favourite is [fuel consumption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuel_economy_in_automobiles#Quantities_and_units_of_measure), which in most countries using the metric system is measured in litres per 100 km. Now (1 L) / (100 km) = 0.01 mm^2 = 1e-9 ha. So 1 litre per 100 km equals a picohectare. ;) I like to think of it as the cross-section area of the stream of fuel that the vehicle consumes.

Comment: @CortAmmon the mathematical functions like logarithms and exponentials and trigonometric functions fully follow and obey unit rules. It is just that you have to specify a length unit to compare against when you use them, because those functions only accept dimensionless quantities.

Comment: @StanislavBashkyrtsev "rate of change of volume", where we are asking for "rate in length" rather than the usual "rate in time", **is** an area. There is simply no replacement of notions. Those two things are literally the same thing.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I've been shooting myself for a long time for not bookmarking it, but there was an article in Metrologia about a decade ago explaining how the units on such functions are not well defined.  As an example, consider dbV and dbA - logarithms of voltage and amperage respectively.  It is hard to axiomatically explain why *adding* those values of completely different units yields dbVA or dbW.  One has to resort to a semantic proof tying it back to the original volts and amps taken before the logarithm.

Comment: Attempts to axiomize unit systems that support logarithmic units run into consistency problems.  When you make it work in one case, it breaks another.

Comment: @CortAmmon I have difficulty seeing why that would be a problem at all, because, again, if you already have a volt-unit and ampere-unit needed for the logarithms, then the sum of those logarithms are literally the multiplication of the arguments of the logarithms, which come out to power-units and power. So I am not sure what that argument even is.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it's completely fine: you can simplify the units to [m$^2$].

In the example with volume and area you can ask the question "what is the change in volume, for some given change in radius?" and the answer will be a volume (units [m$^3$]). But you can also ask the question, "what is the change in volume *divided by* the change in radius?" and then answer will be a volume divided by a length, which yields an area, so the appropriate unit is [m$^2$].

More generally, the expressions for units obey all the usual rules of algebra. For example: to write and inverse centimetre in terms of an inverse metre you can write
$$
\frac{1}{{\rm cm}} = \frac{1}{0.01 {\rm m}} = \frac{100}{\rm m}
$$
so we have
$$
1 \, {\rm cm}^{-1} = 100 \, {\rm m}^{-1}.
$$
Or to write the speed of light in km/s you can use
$$
c = 3 \times 10^8 \, {\rm m/s} = 3 \times 10^8 \, (0.001 \, {\rm km})/{\rm s}
= 3 \times 10^8 \times 0.001 \, {\rm km/s}
= 3 \times 10^5 \, {\rm km/s}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's fine. The area *is* the rate of change, viewed from a certain perspective.

Given a region $\mathcal R\subseteq \mathbb R^3$, we can imagine adding a shell of thickness $\delta$ around $\mathcal R$ and asking how much the volume has increased. More specifically, we can write down a function $V(\delta)$ such that $V(0)\equiv V_0$ is the volume before adding the shell. Once you've done this, $V'(0)$ is a perfectly good definition of the surface area of $\mathcal R$, in which case the surface area is the rate of change of the volume with respect to the shell thickness (evaluated at $\delta=0$).

For example, consider a sphere of (initial) radius $r$. Adding a shell of thickness $\delta$ serves to simply increase the radius to $r+\delta$, and so the volume function is $V(\delta)= \frac{4}{3}\pi (r+\delta)^3$, and the surface area is $V'(0) = 4\pi r^2$.

As a second example, consider a right cylinder with radius $r$ and height $h$. Adding a shell of thickness $\delta$ increases $r$ by $\delta$ and $h$ by $2\delta$ (since the shell is added to the top and to the bottom), so the volume function is $V(\delta) = \pi (r+\delta)^2 (h+2\delta)$, and the surface area is $V'(0) = 2\pi r^2  + 2\pi rh$.